# add widgets to qt-creator designer

Tags: qt, widget, qt-creator, qtwebkit, qt-designer

I'm new to using Qt and many of the tutorials I read online demonstrated on how to develop a simple web browser. I'm using Qt Creator as the IDE.

The problem I'm facing is that in the designer of Qt Creator there is no WebView or any other web widget for me to drag and drop. Earlier even .pro file and .cpp files were giving errors when I typed QT += webkit or included QtWebKit library in them respectively. But then I ran

```
sudo apt-get install libqt5webkit5-dev
```

on the terminal and .pro and .cpp stopped giving those errors. But I still can't figure out how to add widgets to the designer.

My Qt Creator version is `3.1.1` and Qt version is `5.2.1`.

Answer (score 0):

you must remove your qt & qt-creator then install it again, 
if this problem doesn't solve, download offline QT from Qt site:

(32bit)(http://download.qt-project.org/official_releases/qt/5.3/5.3.2/qt-opensource-linux-x86-5.3.2.run)
(64bit)(http://download.qt-project.org/official_releases/qt/5.3/5.3.2/qt-opensource-linux-x64-5.3.2.run)

and install from offline version which is more complete than command line version.
I had this problem and I had to re-install it completely.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem for me, working on Linux Mint: in the qt creator there is no webview or any other web widget to drag and drop. 
I solved editing the UI file (a simple xml) with this:

```
<widget class="QWebView" name="myWebView">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>10</x>
     <y>10</y>
     <width>381</width>
     <height>181</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <property name="url">
    <url>
     <string>about:blank</string>
    </url>
   </property>
  </widget>
```

save the ui file and open it with Qt Creator: you can now view and modify the widget.

Answer (score 0):

First things first (for any reading this old ?): Although it wasn't released at the time of your posting, they have a new web engine with Qt 5.5.  Opera is based on Webkit.  For whatever reasons, the Qt people now recommend using Qt WebEngine, which is based on Chromium (the privacy-enhanced version of Chrome).  Many expect it to be faster in most cases.

There is a guide to adding a widget to the palette in Qt Designer here:

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/designer-creating-custom-widgets.html

It is an example aimed at using it in Qt Designer, but should have helpful info.  If you want to use one in the very similar form designer in Qt Creator, here are a few threads that have Qt Creator-specific instructions:

https://forum.qt.io/topic/6100/how-do-i-add-a-custom-widget-to-qt-creator

https://forum.qt.io/topic/37558/unable-to-figure-out-how-to-add-custom-widget-in-qt-creator/2

Comment: It is not recommended to have many external links, which may stop working after a while, consider adding these steps in your answer if possible.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow){
ui->setupUi(this);
mWebView = new QWebView;
QString url = "http://***yoursite****";
mWebView->load(url);
setCentralWidget(mWebView);}﻿
```